# Understanding Sed command with extended RegExp

Tags: sed, regular-expression, text-formatting

I'm currently using this one-liner to get the latest release version of `docker-compose`.

`curl --silent "https://api.github.com/repos/docker/compose/releases/latest" | grep "tag_name" | sed -E 's/.*"([^"]+)".*/\1/'`

This isn't my code. 
I copied & pasted it, and it worked, and I wanted to learn more. 
Specifically, I am very interested in the `sed` command. 
Can anyone help me understand it better?

`sed -E 's/.*"([^"]+)".*/\1/'`

Essentially I don't understand any of the string. 
I know the items individually
(`.*` = any character one or more, `[^"]` = accept anything that isn't `"`). 
But when it is written in that way I am unsure how it works out.

Output of command without the `sed` command: `"tag_name": "1.22.0",`

Output of command with the `sed` command: `1.22.0`

Comment: which `sed`? my gnu `sed`, does not have `-E`

Comment: Which parts of regex are you struggling with? What do you understand so far?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor GNU `sed` has supported `-E` (a la BSD) for a while now (4.2 in 2009) even though it was initially undocumented (documented in 4.3 2017). `-E` is going to make it to the POSIX standard. GNU `sed` had `-r` initially for that.

Comment: It may make more sense to use a JSON parsing tool here. Like `jq -r .tag_name`.

Comment: Yes jq will be more stable, as json can be formatted onto one line etc etc etc.

Comment: Essentially I don't understand any of the string. I know the items individually (.* = any character 1 or more & [^"] = accept anything that isn't "). But when it is written in that way I am unsure how it works out.

I should have added - this isn't my code. I'm afraid this is a Google copy & paste that worked, and I wanted to learn more.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`sed -E 's/.*"([^"]+)".*/\1/`

- `-E`: `sed` will use Extended Regex
- 's': to substitute value.
- `/`: the separator of pattern and replacement that will be use.
- `.*"([^"]+)".*`: the best way I know to explain regex is a graph:
  [image: regex explantation]
  Basically it matches every line that have two block of quotes and put the second one (without the quotes) inside group one.
- `/`: separator between your regexp and your replacement
- `\1`: replace your original line with the group number 1 : `1.22.0` in this case.
- `/`: last separator without option after it so it will replace only once a line.

Hope this is explain well enough.
If you need to read a regex in a more visual way you can use [the site regexper](https://regexper.com) which is amazing.

Comment: This is wrong. The regex does not match every line that ***has*** two ***blocks*** of quotes; it matches every line that has two or more quote characters (so it could be just a single pair).  And it doesn’t capture the second “block of quotes”; it captures the ***last*** one.  To be more precise, it captures whatever is between the last two quotes; it will capture `c` from ```a"b"c"d```, even though that doesn’t make much sense.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' minor correction: it matches every line that has two or more double quotes, *with at least 1 character in between them that is not also a double quote*. It cannot just be a single pair (`echo \"\" | sed -E 's/.*"([^"]+)".*/foo/'` does not print `foo`)

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what you know about `sed`. 
In [sed(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html) you may find:

> sed - stream editor for filtering and transforming text

and:

> **`-E`**, **`-r`**, **`--regexp-extended`**
>
>       use extended regular expressions in the script
>       (for portability use POSIX
>       `-E`
>       ).

In `sed` you could define, let me say, *word pattern* between parentheses
and you could substitute
them with `\` (backslash) followed by a one-digit number. 
In your question, let me write as below:

```
echo '"tag_name": "1.22.0"' | sed -E 's/"([a-z]+\_[a-z]+)": "([0-9\.]+)"/\2/'
```

- `-E` use extended regular expressions
- `'s/Part1/Part2/` the main structure
- `"` regex pattern starts with `"`
- `([a-z]+\_[a-z]+)` first *word pattern* contains two part of chars joined with `_`
- `": "` after that these sequence symbols would occur
- `([0-9\.]+)` the second *word pattern* contains one or more
  digits with **`.`**
- `"` pattern ends with it.
- `\2` now you call the second *word pattern*

Comment: The question asks about a specific ``sed`` command, and you present a *similar* command and explain it.  Why not just answer the question?

Comment: because he told:'Can anyone help me understand it better?' and knew somethings of Regex.